# Replicate Stored Procedures between MS Databases

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures, replication, database-administration

I want a solution that match the below scenario:

We have 2 databases with 1 being the main DB and the other being the secondary DB. I want a process (executable, powershell, anything...) that can update the changes that I make in Stored Procedures in the main DB. the main DB is the database that we will make the changes then I want a process that update (simple delete and create) the older SP in the secondary DB.

How I can make this possible in the most simply way? If you will say software to work with please take in account that I only want freeware.

Comment: Your 4th tag is "replication". Have you [looked into that?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017) :)

Comment: Maybe DDL triggers on the main DB. Or, you could train your DBAs/developers to deploy to both databases. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like you are defining something called Mirroring if I didn't assume wrong.

Database mirroring maintains two copies of a single database that must reside on different server instances of SQL Server Database Engine. Typically, these server instances reside on computers in different locations. Starting database mirroring on a database, initiates a relationship, known as a database mirroring session, between these server instances.

One server instance serves the database to clients (the principal server). The other instance acts as a hot or warm standby server (the mirror server), depending on the configuration and state of the mirroring session. When a database mirroring session is synchronized, database mirroring provides a hot standby server that supports rapid failover without a loss of data from committed transactions. When the session is not synchronized, the mirror server is typically available as a warm standby server (with possible data loss).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response but I have the 2 database in the same instance/server and not separately. The process it's mainly to update only stored procedures and I think this solution it's more technical. The objective is to replicate the changes from one DB to another  for not to use DROP AND CREATE and only work with the main DB because I will have more 3 Databases that will have common SP and I don't want to have to change all SP in all DB...